# PHP - Save the selected item from the MySQL in $ _SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, session

There is a script 1.php

```
session_start();
$sql_1 = "SELECT ID,text,dt FROM Notes WHERE username='test' ORDER BY ID DESC ";
$result_1 = $conn->query($sql_1);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1)){
... + A link on the view.html
$_SESSION["ID"] = $fetch['ID'];
...
```

And the script 2.php

```
session_start();
$ID = ($_SESSION["ID"]);
$sql_1 = "SELECT text FROM Notes WHERE username='test' AND ID = '$ID'";
$result_1 = $conn->query($sql_1);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1)){
echo  '<p>'.$fetch['text'].'</p>';
}
```

On page view.html I "call" the script 2.php using Ajax.

The problem is, in fact that only the first session ID is stored.
For example, if the query get the list of IDs' the SESSION will be stored only 
ID with number "1", but not 2 or etc.
How to get a second or third (ie the user chooses from a list of the links with  the required ID). For instance, there are a list of links with different ID. User want to open the second link. The SESSION need to "remember" this ID and on the view.html will display the text of the second link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: updated answer again, last example in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the session variable an array, then append the rows to each array piece

```
session_start();
$ID = ($_SESSION["ID"]);
$sql_1 = "SELECT text FROM Notes WHERE username='test' AND ID = '$ID'";
$result_1 = $conn->query($sql_1);
$_SESSION['data'] = array();
$iCount = 0;
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1)){
    echo  '<p>'.$fetch['text'].'</p>';
    $_SESSION['data'][$iCount] = $fetch['text'];
    $iCount++;
}
```

Of you can do this....

```
session_start();
$ID = ($_SESSION["ID"]);
$sql_1 = "SELECT text FROM Notes WHERE username='test' AND ID = '$ID'";
$result_1 = $conn->query($sql_1);
$_SESSION['data'] = array();
$iCount = 0;
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1)){
    echo  '<p>'.$fetch['text'].'</p>';
    $_SESSION['data'][$iCount] = $fetch;
    $iCount++;
}
foreach ($_SESSION['data'] as $oSessData) {
    echo "Text: ", $oSessData['text'], "<br />";
}
```

As Mentioned In Comments: by (user3036342)

```
// CALL THIS ONLY ONCE, SAY WHEN THE USER LOGS ON... Calling it twice will clear it.
$_SESSION['data'] = array();


session_start();
$ID = ($_SESSION["ID"]);
$sql_1 = "SELECT text FROM Notes WHERE username='test' AND ID = '$ID'";
$result_1 = $conn->query($sql_1);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1)){
    echo  '<p>'.$fetch['text'].'</p>';
    $_SESSION['data'][] = $fetch['text']; // this will append to the array
}
foreach ($_SESSION['data'] as $oSessData) {
    echo "Text: ", $oSessData, "<br />";
}
```

**EDIT**

The last example will create an array once for the session (note only call that part once) and then the while loop will append to that array any time it finds a single or multiple rows.

```
// CALL THIS ONLY ONCE, SAY WHEN THE USER LOGS ON... Calling it twice will clear it.
session_start();
$_SESSION['data'] = array();
```

Make sure the above code has been run at a different time, Every time you run this code, it will set the data variable to an empty array. So run it when you first login or visit the page.

The code below can then be run as may times as you want, each time it will append the values to it.

```
// Store them by id
session_start();
$ID = ($_SESSION["ID"]);
$sql_1 = "SELECT text FROM Notes WHERE username='test' AND ID = '$ID'";
$result_1 = $conn->query($sql_1);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1)){
    echo  '<p>'.$fetch['text'].'</p>';
    $_SESSION['data'][$ID] = $fetch['text']; // this will assign a by a index/key
}
foreach ($_SESSION['data'] as $oSessData) {
    echo "Text: ", $oSessData, "<br />";
}
// or access them directly if they are known...
echo "Text: ", $oSessData[77], "<br />"; // if user 77 is in the array
```

**Another Thought**

By the looks of your session variable, you are opening one account into a session.. grabbing the text value... If you are then going into another session or user session, you need to transfer your session array to a php array while you regenerate your new session.

Else each time you kill your session, you are losing all the data in it.. I get a feeling the issue is a step or two before the code that you have pasted.. Are you logging into to multiple sessions of some form?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. The issue here is the 2nd piece of code is called via client-side script (AJAX) and he isn't passing back what is in the session from the first call to append the second call. It seems people are increasingly not understanding that client-side scripting can't interact with server-side scripting without a bit of footwork

Comment: True, its hard to tell with the current example though.. I Guess looking at the query it should only return a single each time.

Comment: Think i've covered it now?

Comment: Sorry guys, but no one method does not work. It again return to me the first ID from MySQL. Maybe it is possible to store an array in SESSION on 1.php? And then on 2.php get the "right" ID?

Comment: This is using an array for php sessions, did you use session_start(); before $_SESSION['data'] = array();  make sure that part is on a separate section/procedure in your script. If you copy and paste it, it will not work.

Comment: Yes, of course I user session_start() before $_SESSION.  As you can see now I use just one user "test". 
 Can I user "GET method" to  get data from 1.php to 2.php (but request data from view.html to 2.php via Ajax)?

Comment: Not sure i understand correctly, can you post/edit your question to include a example of this?

Comment: Actually I use PhoneGap... On client side I have index.html (where I load the list of links from 1.php via Ajax), and on the second page - view.html I need to show the detailed information about links - info (like an address book). I try to you GET-method, but PhoneGap did not recognize the links with .php?id= on client's side. The main issue is - how to get the selected ID from index.html to view.html (via Ajax and PHP).